# Variable products - Cost of optional extras depends on size selection

Tags: product, configurable-product, price, magento-community, bundled-product

I have one product, a garden shed, and it's available in 2 choices of cladding with 7 optional extras.

I would like the customer to be able to select the size of the shed they want and for the cost of the cladding and optional extras to then change accordingly.

Please see image to illustrate this price structure.

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible in Magento Community? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: what have you tried so far, it looks doable with a configurable product to me. Maybe easier with a bundle product.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Julien. I've created a configurable product made up of simple products. For example, 10x6 in 12mm and 10x6 in 19mm and each one has the optional extras within it. The optional extras don't show though, so from what I understand I would need to create a simple product for each variation including the extras, which would end up being 100's of products for this one shed alone. This seems very long winded?

Comment: I may be wrong, but you could just use simple dropdowns on your simple product page, and have them have an impact on the product price, which would be way easier than a configurable product, but it would require some dev.

Comment: OK I'll have a look and see what I can come up with. Thanks for your help, it's been really useful

Comment: glad I could guide you, but please come back and put an answer to your own question if you find the perfect fit for your problem, it might be useful for others :)